# Partial string matching across a Pandas Series of Keywords, and a separate DF containing headlines, and other data to be aggregated

Tags: python, pandas

I have one pandas dataframe containing articles, (their ids, headlines and pageview figures), and a separate pandas series containing Entities extracted from these headlines as strings. I want to return a number of series to join to the entities series, including a count of the number of articles which contain the string, and the sum of the pageviews of articles which have the string in the headline.

I am currently trying to loop through my dataframe with a combination of iteritems and iterrows but it is very slow. This is the code for returning a list of the IDs for each entity :

the entity series contains values such as:

```py
"manchester", "Alex Ferguson", "M62"
```

Article data frame would look like

```py
metadata_post_id | metadata_title                        | pageviews 
1234560          | "roadworks on m62 outside manchester" | 4562
7851570          | "driver drives wrong way up m62"      | 10000
4534722          | "Sir Alex Ferguson gets all clear"    | 123
```

Result should be

```py
Entity          | Articles         | Count of articles | Sum of pageviews
"manchester"    |[1234560]         | 1                 | 4562
"Alex Ferguson" |[4534722]         | 1                 | 123
"M62"           |[1234560,7851570] | 2                 | 14562
```

```py
df_list = {}

for index,s in entities_df["entitites"].str.lower().iteritems():
  row_list = []

  for i, r in article_df[["metadata_post_id", "metadata_title", "pageviews"]].drop_duplicates(["metadata_post_id","metadata_title"]).iterrows():
    if r[1].lower().count(s) > 0 :
      row_list.append(r[0])
    #else:
      #row_list.append([i,None,None,None])
  df_list[index] = row_list
```

The desired output would be a dictionary of lists that contain the ids for each entity, the count of the number of headlines the entity appears in, and the sum of pageviews of articles that where the entity appears in the headline.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried using a [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to process the text, and then group on the processed values ?

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and see if I can get my head round it.

Answer (score 0):

After computing `df_list`, the hard job is finished: you have just to use it to build the resulting dataframe.

Using your code, I have obtained `df_list = {0: [1234560], 1: [4534722], 2: [1234560, 7851570]}`, here is code to go one step further:

```
resul = entities_df.copy()
resul['Articles'] = pd.Series(df_list)
resul['Count of articles'] = resul.Articles.apply(lambda x: len(x))
resul['Sum of pageviews'] = resul.Articles.apply(lambda x:
                 article_df.set_index('metadata_post_id').loc[x, 'pageviews'].sum())
```

It gives as expected:

```
          Entity            Articles  Count of articles  Sum of pageviews
0     manchester           [1234560]                  1              4562
1  Alex Ferguson           [4534722]                  1               123
2            M62  [1234560, 7851570]                  2             14562
```

---

After your comment I realized that you used both `iteritems` and `iterrows` which are both terribly inefficient in pandas. You will need to loop once on your entities, but could try to use pandas functions on the article dataframe.

I have not benchmarked it, but you could try this code:

```
def process_entity(string):
    stringl = string.lower()
    df = article_df[article_df.metadata_title.str.lower().str.contains(stringl)]
    artlist = df.metadata_post_id.agg(list)
    artsum = df.pageviews.sum()
    artcount=df.metadata_title.count()
    return [string, artlist, artcount, artsum]

resul = pd.DataFrame(
    [process_entity(string) for string in entities_df.Entity.values],
    columns=['Entity', 'Articles', 'Count of articles', 'Sum of pageviews'])
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Apologies, I should have been clearer, my main issue is the speed of the loop I posted for calculating `df_list`. It it currently taking a couple of hours and I wanted to know if there is any way I would be able to speed it up. I should have said that my actual series and dataframe are 10,000s of rows long. Thank you for the apply +lambda solution for the counts and sum. I will use that as that should speed things up.

Comment: @steak_ale_piethon: Please have a look to my alternative solution